# How the javascript event queue works when we have multiple setTimeouts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am thinking of making a carousel with the help of `fadeIn`, `fadeOut` and `setTimeout`. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sonpuyzn/2/).

I am really confused with the javascript event queue. Because, in the above example, I have used two divs and tried to `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` them in regular time intervals. But, this is not happening in regular intervals. The second div disappears quicker than the first one.

Is it possible to make them have a regular interval?

Comment: _setTimeout(fade($('.top'),$('.bottom')),3000);_ `setTimeout` call is useless here cause you pass **returning value** (of `fade()` call) instead of function. So `fade()` is invoked immediately and then nothing is happen.

Comment: So, what might be the solution @hindmost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what to say about the event queue, but you can fix your code with just a boolean.

```
var isTopTurn = true; //boolean to remember which one should fade
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(fadeHelper,3000);
});


function fade(top, bottom) {
    top.fadeOut(2000);
    bottom.fadeIn(2000);
}


function fadeHelper() {
    if (isTopTurn) {
        isTopTurn = false;
        fade($('.top'), $('.bottom'));

    } else {
        fade($('.bottom'), $('.top'));
        isTopTurn = true;
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5rxceamL/16/)

Comment: Perfect! When we don't use multiple setTimeout / setInterval etc., js event queue looks simple like this. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery, your code is executed asynchronously. That means the code doesn't wait for your called function to finish to move to the next call, it calls a function and moves to the next.

What you need to do is call one `setTimeout` with your `fade` function and inside that function call another `setTimeout` to `fadeIn/fadeOut` your divs like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(fadeHelper,6000);
});

function fade(top,bottom){
    top.fadeOut(2000);
    bottom.fadeIn(2000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        bottom.fadeOut(2000);
        top.fadeIn(2000);
    },3000);
}

function fadeHelper(){    
    setTimeout(fade($('.top'),$('.bottom')),3000);
}
```

Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sonpuyzn/8/).

---

**Edit:** <s>Since you want the fading to start 3 seconds form the beginning you have to set the time on `setInterval` to 3 seconds and remove the `setTimeout` in the `fadeHelper` function.

Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sonpuyzn/9/).</s> Nevermind

Comment: For the first time, its taking 6 seconds to switch between divs. Then on, it takes just 3 seconds. Tricky event queue...

Comment: That is because your `setInterval` is set to 6 seconds. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sonpuyzn/9/) which should be 3 seconds from the start.

Comment: Now, it takes 3 secs for first time. 1.5 secs after that. 3 secs or 6 secs does'nt matters. I need it to happen in a regular interval.